# Congratulations once again, André!!!

Tags: discussion, reputation, specific-user

From today André Nicolas is the [top MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all) user. 
Congratulations André!

Comment: So the top user is not Arturo Magidin anymore. It's quite impressive to earn 60 reputations points by day (in mean) for someone _who didn't logged in since more than six months_. This makes André's performance greatest again.

Comment: Congratulations, André! Meanwhile, I also miss Arturo Magidin.

Comment: The target has changed ;-)

Comment: @Davide, I'm more impressed by the fact that he had cap days even when he wasn't around...

Comment: @DavideGiraudo Although technically Arturo logged in on October 17, 2012; his last activity on Math.SE was on July 26, 2012. It makes more than **nine** months without any activity. His daily reputation record since July 27, 2012 is 140, reached twice. Source: [his reputation chart](http://i.stack.imgur.com/giUk8.png).

Comment: I found that StackExchange has nicer reputation graphs than individual sites. For the current Top 5 users thet are: [André Nicolas](http://stackexchange.com/users/510889/andre-nicolas?tab=reputation), [Arturo Magidin](http://stackexchange.com/users/505553/arturo-magidin?tab=reputation), 
[Brian M. Scott](http://stackexchange.com/users/512076/brian-m-scott?tab=reputation), [Qiaochu Yuan](http://stackexchange.com/users/127441/qiaochu-yuan?tab=reputation), 
[Did](http://stackexchange.com/users/509631/did?tab=reputation).